# Convert QuerySet to python list in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, list

I have this script:

```
lec_name = request.POST['selected_name']
data = Schedules.objects.filter(name=lec_name)
data_list = data.values_list('schedule', flat=True)
print(data_list)
```

This gives below OUTPUT:

```
<QuerySet ["[['1', 'Subject 01', 'Hall 01', 'Tuesday'], ['2', 'Subject 02', 'Hall 03', 'Monday']]"]>
```

Then I tried below script to convert `data_list` to a list:

```
converted_list = list(data_list)
```

This gives below OUTPUT:

```
["[['1', 'Subject 01', 'Hall 01', 'Tuesday'], ['2', 'Subject 02', 'Hall 03', 'Monday']]"]
```

This works fine. But I'm not getting the expected output properly.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**:

```
[['1', 'Subject 01', 'Hall 01', 'Tuesday'], ['2', 'Subject 02', 'Hall 03', 'Monday']]
```

How can I solve this? I found a lot of answers about this, but none helped. I'm using Python 3.7.4, Django 3.0.1

**UPDATE**

Here is my `Schedules` model:

```
class Schedules(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=224)
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hall_n_time = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    schedule = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

`hall_n_time` and `schedule` columns in database, They have two python lists as strings. For an example, schedule column stores `[['1', 'Subject 01', 'Hall 01', 'Tuesday'], ['2', 'Subject 02', 'Hall 03', 'Monday']]` list as a string.

Comment: Are you very sure your `data_list` gives that output? It looks off.

Comment: Yes. Very sure. @Hoenie

Comment: show us your model, what is stored in schedule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assumed that [`values_list`](http://values_list) `flat` parameter would decode json string which is not the case.

It just returns single value instead of tuple

> If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the flat
>   parameter. If True, this will mean the returned results are single
>   values, rather than one-tuples

It returns exactly as mentioned, an array of schedule strings ( could be more of them )

```
["[['1', 'Subject 01', 'Hall 01', 'Tuesday'], ['2', 'Subject 02', 'Hall 03', 'Monday']]"]
```

you still need to [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) your JSON string to decode it

```
converted_list = [json.loads(item) for item in data_list]
```

Comment: Thank you @iklinac.